# Why can't a template reference type be used as a template typealias argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently writing an iterator for a custom collection-style class. I had a mutable iterator class that worked perfectly, but decided it would be best to also implement a const version that would block modifications of the object whose contents are being iterated. I decided to avoid a separate class and code repetition by using a suggestion I found online to use conditional typing.

I defined the `iterator_traits` typealiases in the typical C++11 fashion that would allow code-sharing and template argument-dependent const or mutable behavior (ItemType is a template parameter on the outer container class):

```cpp
template<bool Const = false>
class iterator {
public:
    using reference = std::conditional_t<Const, const ItemType &, ItemType &>;
    using pointer = std::conditional_t<Const, const ItemType *, ItemType *>;

    //Rest of the iterator_traits and some other typealiases

    ...

    template<bool _Const = Const>
    std::enable_if_t<_Const, value_type>
    operator*() const
    {
        //Return copy
    }
     //Non-const version
    template<bool _Const = Const>
    std::enable_if_t<!_Const, reference>
    operator*()
    {
        //Return modifiable reference type
    }
    ...
}
```

I decided to try to remove the repetitive `std::conditional_t` calls by creating another template typealias like this:

```cpp
template<typename type>
using const_conditional = std::conditional_t<Const, const type, type>;
```

and replacing all the `std::conditional_t<...>` with `const_conditional<some_type_here>`. This seems to work universally for the outer class template parameter `ItemType` type, but not for the outer class type itself when its type is a reference, as in `const_conditional<MyCollection<ItemType> &>`. Upon compiling, the compiler complains that I am discarding qualifiers, meaning the `const` isn't being applied, so I'm therefore breaking const requirements, yet replacing my custom typealias with the original `std::conditional_t` code compiles and works just as expected, and I have no clue why.

I can of course simply go back to using the `std::conditional_t` calls I was using originally, which worked fine, but they seemed bloated and repetitive, and I don't understand why my custom typealias fails. Searches across the internet failed to help me in my specific situation. Any help would be very sincerely appreciated.

Comment: A [MCVE] of the code that fails to compile, but would do what you want if it did, would be most helpful.  Please add it to your question.

Comment: and the exact error or warning message, "the compiler complains" can mean either

Comment: `const type` = `T& const` (non-existent) not `const T&`

Answer (score 2):

`ItemType&` and `ItemType*` are types themselves, and so adding a const qualifier yields `ItemType& const` (in which case `const` is silently ignored as a result of template argument substitution) and `ItemType* const`, respectively, which is different than expected `const ItemType&` and `const ItemType*`. For the latter, you could use:

```
template <typename type>
using const_conditional = std::conditional_t<Const, const type, type>;
// ...

using reference = const_conditional<ItemType>&;
using pointer = const_conditional<ItemType>*;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f58bc90b35911fb3)

---

As a side note, `_Const` is a reserved identifier, as all other that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter.